# mapping a sector under a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Help needed below with mapping an area of sector

> Consider the function, $z\in \mathbb{C}$
>   $$ u+iv=f(z)=f(x+iy)=\frac{1}{2} \Big(z+\frac{1}{z}\Big) $$
>
> 1. Determine the domain of analyticity of $f(z)$

For this use Cauchy-Reimann $u_x=v_y\,$, $u_y=-v_x$ to get $y^2=x^2\implies y=\pm x$

> 2. Find the image of the locus $|z|=R$ discussing the cases $R>1$, $R<1$ and $R=1$

For $R=1$, $z=\cos\theta$, so it maps onto the line $z\in [-1,1]$

Substitute $z=r(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)$ to get $w=u+iv$
$$ u=\frac{1}{2} (r+\frac{1}{r})\cos\theta \\ v=\frac{1}{2} (r-\frac{1}{r})\sin\theta$$
which I think looks like an ellipse $$\frac{u^2}{(r+1/r)^2}+\frac{v^2}{(r-1/r)^2}=\frac{1}{2}^2$$

Not sure about where the ellipse is outside and where it is inside the unit circle for the cases $R\neq1$.

> 3. Find the image of the finite region of the complex plane bounded by the curves $z_1=\rho$, $z_2=\rho e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}$, with $0\leq \rho \leq 1$, and $|z_3|=1$

I understand this is a $45$ degrees slice from a unit circle, and that it maps onto and ellipse, but not sure exactly how, and what is the most efficient way to do this - but I am thinking that the image will be un-bounded sector.

**UPDATE**
For 3. I think the image is the inside of a hyperbola as shaded below - but still not entirely sure I am correct:
[image: image of map of sector]

The hyberbolic equation $(u/\cos\theta)^2-(v/\sin\theta)^2=4$ is attained from eliminating $r$ from the equations for $u$ and $v$ above.

> 4. Determine the points for which the map $f(z)$ is not conformal; compute the factor by which angles between the tangents to two lines outgoing from such points get multiplied under the map

$$f(z)=\frac{1}{2}(z+\frac{1}{z})\\
f'(z)=\frac{1}{2}(1-\frac{1}{z^2})=0\\
\implies z=\pm 1$$

Not sure how best to compute the factor for the angles

> 5. For a generic analytic function $g(z)$, find the condition under which the angles between the tangents to two lines outgoing from a point $z$ get multiplied by a factor $m\in \mathbb{N}$ under the map

Not so sure about this either

Thank you

Comment: For 1. I think it is analytic on $\mathbb{C}\backslash\{0\}$.

Comment: My [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2390783/a-mapping-of-the-interior-of-unit-circle-to-the-exterior-of-an-ellipse/2409278#2409278) to a related question may be of interest to you.

Comment: @MyGlasses I see where you're coming from but aren't the C-R equations necessarily satisfied for analyticity?

Comment: How do you compute $u_x$.?

Comment: @MyGlasses from the function $f(x+iy)=u+iv; \, u,v,x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ (sorry I should mention this above, will edit it) and then partially differentiate $u$ wrt $x$